# Is there a way with Solr to search fuzzy AND exact?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot-rails, fuzzy-search, exact-match

thank you for taking your time

### Problem

I have a problem with searching records based on a fuzzy name search and an exact Regio search. This is what I have now:

### What I have now

```
# :klantnaam is a param from a search-form
@param = Staffingcustomer.search do
    fulltext params[:klantnaam]
end
@staffingcustomers = @param.results
```

There is another field, 'Regio'.
The results should only be with a certain 'Regio'.

### Example requirements

So for example,
I'm a user with Regio 3.
I want to visualize/select all Staffingcustomers with Fuzzy name search Anne and my own Regio 3. So, I don't want to see Staffingcustomers with Regio 2.

What happens now is:

```
@param = Staffingcustomer.search do
     fulltext 'anne'
end
@staffingcustomers = @param.results
```

Will return all Staffingcustomers with all different Regios...

### After some research / logic thinking

I think it could be something like the following:

```
@param = Staffingcustomer.search do
    fulltext params[:klantnaam]
end
@staffingcustomers = @param.results.find(:all, :conditions => {:regio => 3})
```

or

```
@param = Staffingcustomer.search do
    fulltext params[:klantnaam] and fulltext '3'   ## or 3, without the quotes
end
@staffingcustomers = @param.results
```

But that just doesn't seem to work.

Can you help me with this issue?

#### The logic problem

Actually this is a fuzzy search on an 'exact selected' part of a huge table.

Hope you can help.

Thanks in advance.

Kers.

Comment: http://www.pipetodevnull.com/past/2010/8/5/fuzzy_searching_in_solr_with_sunspot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
# find Staffing Customers with Regio 3 and text of params[:klantnaam]
@param = Staffingcustomer.search do
  with(:regio, 3)
  fulltext params[:klantnaam]
end
@staffingcustomers = @param.results
```

Refer to https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#readme . You'll also have to index regio in Searchable block of your Staffingcustomer model as whatever data type you stored in the DB (integer, for example).

Comment: Thank you, this indeed should do it. I haven't tested it yet, because I figured a way around. First I selected all Staffingcustomers where :regio => 3, then I fired a fuzzy search on it. That works.
But thanks again, I appreciate your referral.